# Apply Mask from camera RAW

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask, adobe-camera-raw

I have used the masking tool from camera raw:

[image]

Now when I open that thing in PS the layer masks are not there. It is a single layer:

[image]

How do I transfer the layer masks from Camera Raw over to Photoshop?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, masks in Adobe Camera RAW are not the same as layer masks in Photoshop proper.

Comment: really? then whats the point of camera raw masks?

Comment: I think it's so you can make selective adjustments right inside the Camera RAW filter.

Comment: Yes, I have this same question??? Why would you go to all the trouble of masking in Camera Raw, when you can't open up the applied Mask in Photoshop???? Can anyone help explain the "preferred" workflow? Thanks.

Comment: I know this is an old question but, I thought I would add...the reason why it's not possible in ACR is because it doesn't have layer support. So, to output a layer would take adding layer support to ACR. Which is, essentially, a complete rewrite of how ACR works. So it's not likely to happen anytime soon, if at all. Layers are what Photoshop is for, I doubt they would go through the trouble of adding it to ACR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also looking for a way to transfer masks from CR to PS. Looks like the only way to overcome the lack of such functionality is to duplicate the layer, modify it in CR in such a way that it becomes a mask itself (I mean, making the image looking pretty much monochromatic), click OK, copy the result, switch to the layer we want to work on and then apply the copied b&w image as a mask. This solution is not perfect, I know, but at least we have some workaround.

Comment: +1. I was waiting for someone to post this answer. I didn't post it myself as I found it difficult to force Camera Raw to make the mask span from completely black to completely white and I needed to tweak the result afterwards with levels. It's easy to ruin the finer details this way. But it's possible as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, no way to use a LR or ACR mask in PS. LR and ACR added all this masking prowess but no way to use it to remove or replace the background. They both added a Replace Sky function, so maybe in the future they maybe will add? Because neither object selection or select object or refine edge brush will select hair very well at all still on PS 2023 for me...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/113590)

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anyway to transfer the mask from one to the other; the reason for the masking in ACR is to fine tune the photo without affecting all elements.  For example maybe you want to reduce exposure to the background and increase exposure to the subject.  Or soften the subject without softening other elements.  With the brush mask I was able to exclude the eyes from a facial mask and then soften it without softening the eyes.  I then decreased exposure and increased shadowing and other elements to the background to create better separation.  I realize pretty much all of this is available in Photoshop, but not in the RAW image itself.

I agree that I hope they make some transferability of a mask from one to the other at some point or put the same tech in PS as ACR.